# Laravel Pagination with row count

Tags: laravel, pagination

How to add row number of each row in a table? I used pagination but found it difficult to display the row count. In page 2, It should be starting 6 since my pagination is 5 per page.

**EDIT**

And also how to display correctly the word `showing 1 to 5 of 2095` above the table?

[image]

**CONTROLLER**

```
class SchoolController extends Controller
{
    function index()
    {
        $q = Input::get('q');
        if ($q != "") {
            $schools = LibSchool::where('school_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                ->orWhere('school_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                ->orWhere('address', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                ->orWhere('school_head', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                ->orWhere('level', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                ->orderBy('school_name', 'asc')
                ->with('libdistrict')
                ->with('libdistrict.libdivision')
                ->paginate(5)->appends('q', $q);
        } else {
            $schools = LibSchool::with('libdistrict')
                ->orderBy('school_name', 'asc')
                ->with('libdistrict.libdivision')
                ->paginate(5);
        }
        return view('schools.index')->with('data', ['schools' => $schools, 'q' => $q]);
    }
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<div class="card-body">
        Showing 1 to 15 of {{$data['schools']->total()}}
        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Division</th>
                <th>District</th>
                <th>School ID</th>
                <th>School NAME</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>School Head</th>
                <th>Level</th>

            </tr>
            @if($data['schools']->total() > 0)
            @foreach($data['schools'] as $school)
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>{{ $school->libdistrict ? $school->libdistrict->libdivision->div_name : 'N/A' }}</td>
                <td>{{ $school->libdistrict ? $school->libdistrict->district_name : 'N/A' }}</td>
                <td>{{$school->school_id}}</td>
                <td>{{$school->school_name}}</td>
                <td>{{$school->address}}</td>
                <td>{{$school->school_head}}</td>
                <td>{{$school->level}}</td>

            </tr>
            @endforeach
            @else
            <td colspan="7" class="text-danger">No records</td>
            @endif
        </table>
        {{$data['schools']->links()}}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this one,

```
<td>{{ ($data['schools']->currentPage()-1) * $data['schools']->perPage() + $loop->index + 1 }}</td>
```

Current page gives the page number and $loop variable gives index of the current item in the loop so that you calculate the numbering.

You can get the showing 1 to 5 of 2095 like this:

```
Showing {{($data['schools']->currentPage()-1)* $data['schools']->perPage()+($data['schools']->total() ? 1:0)}} to {{($data['schools']->currentPage()-1)*$data['schools']->perPage()+count($data['schools'])}}  of  {{$data['schools']->total()}}  Results
```

I hope you understand.

Comment: thanks this is working. I only need to add 1. However the display of `showing 1 to 5 of 2092` How is that done correctly?

Comment: @beginner I have updated my answer have a try. Feel free to ask if any problem.

Comment: @beginner Great !

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`$loop`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable) variable and the current page to calculate the row number.

```
<td>{{ ($data['schools']->currentPage() - 1) * $data['schools']->perPage() + $loop->iteration }}</td>
```

The calculation is the current page minus one, times the pagesize (to count the previous pages), plus the index on the current page.

Comment: is it ok if I add 1 because it starts from zero. `<td>{{ ($data['schools']->currentPage() - 1) * $data['schools']->perPage() + $loop->index + 1 }}</td>`

Comment: @beginner $loop->index starts from zero, so you can add one for real numbering.

Comment: and also can u help me with the `showing 1 to 5 of 2095`?

Comment: Use `$loop->iteration` instead of `$loop->index`. It starts from 1.

Comment: using `$loop->iteration` will indeed start from one, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since all above answers are missing the out of the box methods

My Answer Will work on Laravel version  **5.0 and Above**

My Current Version **5.8.28**

You Dont need any of the **fuzzy Calculation**

Just Try this

```
showing {{$data['schools']->firstItem()}} to {{$data['schools']->lastItem()}} of {{$data['schools']->total()}}
```

For More  https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.php#L163

EDIT FOR  **method on getting the row numbers**

**Method One**

```
@forelse ($data['schools'] as $school)
{{-- Just Add iteration property of $loop Object --}}
    <td>{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
{{-- All Your Fileds Goes Here --}}
@empty
    <td colspan="7" class="text-danger">No records</td>
@endforelse
```

But it wont work as expected Because Event if you are changing the page the `iteration` property will start from Number 1

So

**Method TWO**

```
{{ ($data['schools']->currentpage()-1) * $data['schools'] ->perpage() + $loop->index + 1 }}
```

And If You prefer even Short Method

```
{{($data['schools']->firstItem() + $loop->index)}}
```

It will give You actual Serial number

If Something Went wrong leave a comment

Comment: is there any another method on getting the row numbers aside from the samples given by other answers?

Comment: what do you mean by row numbers??. Are You Talking About Serial Number??

Comment: the numbers that corresponds to each row. Just like the 1,2,3,4 and 5 in the screenshot above.

Answer (score 1):

To number the items of a collection and add the data on it its as easy as do a foreach loop in the controller, then you have the numbers all the time on the view (btw those dont get stored to the database)

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($schools as $item)
{
$item->setAttribute('number', $i);
$i++;
}
```

and on the view row

```
{{$item->number}}
```

Comment: is this faster from the other answers?

Comment: Not sure but I think its easy and practical

Answer (score 0):

In your controller :

```
$users = User::all()->paginate(3);
return view('/', compact('users'));
```

In your blade

```
@foreach($users as $key => $user)
<tr>
       <td>{{ $users->firstItem() + $key }}</td>
       <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
       <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```